# Sign out programatically from 3rd party systems opened in another tab

Tags: c#, session, authentication, single-sign-on

Our dashboard app which has links to various 3rd party systems uses forms based authentication. When authenticated user clicks the 3rd party system's link, I use `User.Identity.Name` to get the identity and form a POST request for **further** authentication to **that** particular system. Each system opens in a new tab when its link is clicked from our dashboard - dashboard app remains open in previous tab. Signing in is working as expected.

These systems have their own link to sign out. I have tried sending both GET and POST requests programmatically to the sign out url - from the dashboard tab, but that does not work. User signs out from dashboard app successfully, but can still continue to access the 3rd party systems links from the other tab.

How do I sign them out from a 3rd party system, given that I know its sign out url?

Comment: Still waiting for a comment/answer ! :) Do I need to re-word the problem?

Comment: This largely depends on the '3rd parties systems', have you attempted to debug the response when calling the urls? what response are you getting?

Comment: You just post a user name to their system and it is all that is needed to authenticate there? Not a direct answer to your question but sounds like a huge security hole. I hope it only sounds that and the implementation is secure.

Comment: @BenjaminPaul yes, the response is HTML of **that particular** system's sign in page. If I copy paste the logout url of 3rd party in our dashboard app's tab, the user is signed out from **that** system - which is open in another tab. But obviously that's not a practical solution. If I send a GET request to the logout url via HttpWebRequest, I get the HTML of 3rd party's sign in page in response, but I can still browse the 3rd party system.

Comment: @WiktorZychla no, not as simple as that. they have documentation which tells how to generate auth request for a user, which will then be honored based on certain predetermined conditions.

Comment: If the authentication is shared between tabs (cookie for example) then signing out in one tab should sign out on all tabs.

Comment: @WiktorZychla say i have 3 independent systems, each having own programmatic auth mechanism. each having own domain name. own cookie name. each opening in separate tab when link clicked. but the mother dashboard tab is still open. i need to single sign out by clearing all cookies from this mother tab.

Comment: @greatbear302: you just return a page that contains a list of iframes of which each points to a page that is supposed to sign out one of applications. Browser picks up the page, follows all iframes and one by one signs out all applications.

Comment: @WiktorZychla this is so far the best solution. but then making the iframe invisible for cosmetics raises more questions like cross browser compatibility and potential malware warnings. in any case i will mark your comment as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should just return a page that contains a list of iframes of which each points to a page that is supposed to sign out one of applications. Browser picks up the page, follows all iframes and one by one signs out all applications.

You should not be concerned by any issues, this idea is borrowed from the ws-federation specs and it is fully compatible and raises no issues. We use it for years.